# AutoHotKey user input for address bar in browser

Tags: dynamic, input, autohotkey

We get QA Builds frequently with different IP's. I m trying to automate log in to the application with Autohot key. I have reached thus far

InputBox, UserInput, IP, Enter URl., , 640, 480

Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

WinWait, https://$UserInput$/myproj/mylogin.aspx - Internet Explorer`, optimized for Bing and M, Address Combo Contro

Answer (score 1):

Change the $UserInput$ into %UserInput%.

You could probably use all in one line:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" https://%UserInput%/myproj/mylogin.aspx
```